# Is there a better function for finding edges on a list of common nodes?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, networkx

I have a list of nodes and each node has measured the wifi field strength from other points. The list will be in the form:

```
 RSSI_list = [[node4, node3, RSSI], [node7, node5, RSSI]] #etc (it will be more populated)
```

The RSSI can be considered equivalent to an estimated distance as it will be replaced with a value interpolated/extrapolated from some empirical data I have recorded.

I want to find and "map" where all the points are in relation to each other so I can calculate angles between them.

To do this I have looked at using `networkx` which provides the following functions:

```
aGraph.add_nodes_from(aListOfNodes)   # Add all the nodes from the list, aListOfNodes
aGraph.add_edge(aNode1, aNode2) # creates an edge from aNode1 to aNode2

edgeData = {"weight": 42}      # a dictionary with only one entry
g.add_edge(nodeA, nodeB, edgeData)   #create the edge with the given data dictionary
```

Which would allow me to use what I have in my list. I want something that will allow me to add pairs of nodes and will automatically link pairs where an end is common.

Before I go any further down the networkx line of enquiry is there a better function in another python module that would do this better?

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are after... How do you plan on calculating angles from a graph? What exactly is you want to calculate?

Comment: I'm hoping to find the edges that are linked between the points, then I could figure out which of these edges make triangles ie which 3 edges have common points, then find the angles of the triangles.

Comment: Oh, now I see! Your `'weight'`s are proxies for the distance between the nodes. You are still going to have to deal with finding cycles of length 3, not sure if `networkx` will help with that...

Answer (score 3):

`networkx` will do exactly what you want:

```
g = nx.Graph()

for a, b , w in RSSI_list:
    g.add_edge(a, b, {'weight': w})
```

You can then get everything you want by walking the graph.